# Angular compiling error "No suitable injection token "

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

i am trying to use "ngx-mat-select-search" and "ng-multiselect-dropdown", but when i compile the app it says:

```
ERROR in No suitable injection token for parameter 'changeDetectorRef' of class 'MatSelectSearchComponent'.no type or decorator

ERROR in No suitable injection token for parameter 'cdr' of class 'MultiSelectComponent'. no type or decorator
```

any idea whats happening?, i use angular 8 and material angular.

Edit: this is the code:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import {LayoutComponent} from './layout/layout.component';
import {SharedModule} from '@shared/shared.module';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ErrorInterceptor} from '@helper/error.interceptor';
import {JwtInterceptor} from '@helper/jwt.interceptor';
import {BootstrapModule} from './bootstrap/bootstrap.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts';
import {MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {NgMultiSelectDropDownModule} from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BootstrapModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    ChartsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,


  ],
  providers: [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

i am really clueless to what i am missing :(.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the inectable decorator. Show us more code.

Comment: is update, can you see something?

Comment: that's your app module. What is the error message telling you? What is the full stack trace?